# rails 3.1, Why I can't send email using ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, actionmailer

I have problem in my heroku app, I am trying to send email using my Godaddy email account, here is my settings in the environment/production.rb:

```
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'coursebuilder2.heroku.com' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address  => "smtpout.secureserver.net",
    :port  => 25,
    :user_name  => "myemail@domain.com",
    :password  => "password",
    :authentication  => :login
  }

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

but, here is what I get:

```
Rendered instructors/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 666ms

SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):

cache: [POST /instructors] invalidate, pass
```

So, what's I am missing here ?

**EDIT**

I have fixed the settings above, but, now, I have a timeout error below:

```
2012-03-04T04:44:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered instructors/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (0.4ms)
2012-03-04T04:44:50+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> POST coursebuilder2.herokuapp.com/instructors dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-03-04T04:45:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60414ms
2012-03-04T04:45:20+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-04T04:45:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-03-04T04:45:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error):
2012-03-04T04:45:20+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-04T04:45:20+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-04T04:45:20+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /instructors] invalidate, pass
```

Any one can advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like you're using the wrong connection details to GoDaddy - to be honest, I'd be inclined to use the SendGrid free addon which is widely used and documented.